# The graph is not showing up in my jupyter notebook in kaggle

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, kaggle

I am not able to see my plot in my kaggle notebook.
The following is my code.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
import seaborn as sns
```

- 

```
df = pd.read_csv('../input/sdd1247/COMED_hourly.csv', parse_dates=["Datetime"], index_col="Datetime")
```

- 

```
def Visualization_plots(x):
    y = df.loc['2017']
    y['COMED_MW'].resample('H').mean().plot()


button = widgets.Button(
    description='Submit',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='success', # 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger' or ''
    tooltip='Click me',
    icon='alicorn' # (FontAwesome names without the `fa-` prefix)
)
button.on_click(Visualization_plots)
button
```

The button shows up.. but when I click on it, I expected the graph to show below it.  But nothing shows up.
I do however see the graph in the console.  How can I show the graph in my notebook instead?

This is how it shows up in the console window:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would add plt.show() on the line after the plot instruction.
If it doesn't work please provide a few lines of your dataset.